2004 Volvo S40 2.4i, Engine Service Urgent
I just recently bought this S40 about a month ago and has been fine,the last couple days, the idle has been a little rough but no issues, I started the car and Engine Service Urgent popped up with a red triangle, I put a scanner and no codes were found, so I did the shortcut and found the General 020 code in the LCD, which is a vast array of issues, is there any ways to try and Pinpoint without putting in a shop and getting charged a fortune?

Generic readers will not decode manufacturers specific error codes. Emissions error codes are universal for generic readers. Volvo or higher priced aftermarket readers/scantools specifically capable of decoding all Volvo codes is needed. You can try calling repair shops but expect fees if they have scantools to read Volvo codes.
